# How to kill all turtles at once in the NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a 300x300 world with each cell being 10m. I used the sprout command to generate 1 turtles per patch. Each turtle performs a series of procedures, writes the result to the patch and dies. But when dying, 1 turtle will die at a time when using the "die" command. Is there any way to kill all turtles created at once?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#clear-turtles

Comment: Thanks, but when I used:  
to proc1
ask turtles
  [
    set ene (ene - euse)
    ask my-home
    [
      set energy-of-my-agent [ ene ] of my-agent      
    ]
    if outputData? = true [ outputData-1 ]
    ;die  
   
  ]
clear-turtles 
end

appear: you can´t use proc1 in a turtle context, because proc1 is observer-only.

Comment: You should add your code to the question.  `clear-turtles` runs in the observer context, which means it makes your `proc1` also run in the observer context, but you are calling it from somewhere inside an `ask` block, which puts it in the turtle context.  You'll have to call it from outside a turtle context or move the `clear-turtles` to a different spot in your code (which I cannot suggest because I cannot see it).

Answer (score 0):

from observer context.

```
ask turtles [die]
```

from agent context.

```
ask other turtles [die] die
```